# How to format link in email to open an Xpage App

Tags: xpages

I am sending out an HTML email to our users every week in which I want to include links to certain documents and then a link to the overall database. The database is an Xpage db.

On my docs I have a field only visible to me in which I compute the link I need. The format is as follows:

notes://servername/__.nsf/0/?OpenDocument

What I want is the URL to open not just a specific document, but the Xpages app in general. Everything I try opens up the all documents view.

notes://servername/__.nsf/

If I put this in the address bar, it works fine. If I put it in a link, it goes to the all documents view.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If launch options fail, Lotusscript in PostOpen database event will fix it.

Answer (score 1):

You could try formatting it as: `notes://servername/__.nsf/nameOfXpageYouWantToOpenTo.xsp?OpenXPage`

Have you set the launch properties for the database?  You can specify a designated XPage in there too.

[image: Application Properties, Launch Tab]

Comment: Rob, this is really bizarre. I have the launch properties set correctly. I put in my information like you show, with my db name with .nsf and also with the page, but I always open up to a "naked" frame with views on the left and the the docs for that view on the right.  I tried this on another DB that we have that is only Xpages, and it has the same thing. This is exasperating. Does that syntax work for you?

Comment: Naked frame: XPages didn't load. Check the log. A popular catch it mechanism: create a sensible classic frameset (it could contain a static page mentioning that this wasn't intended) and use the frame properties to point to a Composite App page. In that one you point to your XPage. So if it doesn't load you at least have a defined state

Comment: @Bryan I was typing that mostly from memory, forgot the `?OpenXPage` part.  See edited answer.  The launch properties don't seem to have much effect when doing a `notes://` style launch for me

Comment: Rob, awesome, this worked. One of the problems I had was that we have two names for the server (I do not know why we are set up that way.  I wonder if there is a list of these URLs so I can put them in my documentation?

Answer (score 0):

Use this code syntax to open any XPage in the Notes client:

```
 @URLOpen("notes://Host/Path/Database.nsf/XPageName.xsp?OpenXPage")
```

**Additional details:**
And use the following to open a specific document in the XPage where unid is the unique document identifier for the document:

```
 @URLOpen("notes://Host/Path/Database.nsf/XPageName.xsp?documentId=unid&action=openDocument")
```

Answer (score 0):

The format you are looking for is:

```
 notes://servername/yourdb.nsf/someview/unid?OpenDocument
```

in the "someview" view you add a form formula to point to an empty form that has the property set "open XPage instead" - careful there are 2 of them: for web and client.

If you don't use native forms and the Xpage is always the same, then you can skip the step with the form formula and the extra form and edit the properties of the existing form.

Paul's solution should work too.